# iOS - SwiftUI - @State variable value in viewBuilder has old value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using a `LoadingView` view to show an activity indicator before data is loaded. The `LoadingView` receives a `@ViewBuilder` closure to render the content after the data is loaded.

The `@ViewBuilder` closure captures a `@State` variable, but if this state was updated, the `@ViewBuilder` gets the old value for the state.

An easy code snippet is worth thousand words:

```
struct PresenterView: View {
    
    enum PresentationMode {
        case small, big
    }
    
    @State private var presentationMode: PresentationMode = .small
    
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView() { message in
            switch self.presentationMode {
            case .small:
                Text("Small presentation of: \(message)")
            case .big:
                Text("Big presentation of: \(message)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("Presentation mode is changed, before data is loaded")
                self.presentationMode = .big
            }
        }
    }
}


struct LoadingView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State var loaded = false
    
    let content: (String) -> Content
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (String) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if loaded {
                content("Data")
            }
            else {
                Text("Data is still loading")
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                print("Data is loaded")
                self.loaded = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the presentation mode is changed to `.big` **before** the data is loaded. When the `@ViewBuilder` is rendered, it still uses the initial `.small` value.

Some findings:
If presentation mode is changed to `.big` **after** the data is loaded, the `@ViewBuilder` view gets updated properly. It is my understanding, that internally the `@ViewBuilder` view does only bind to the state after it has been presented. Still, it should be possible for the `@ViewBuilder` to get the current value of the state. After all, when the `@ViewBuilder` is presented, the binding to the state works correctly.

Using an `@ObservedObject` to wrap the `presentationMode` works fine, but I would like to avoid this, in order to use `@State` reliable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: fyi it is recommended resolving content() in the init right away and storing the result rather than storing the view builder: https://onmyway133.com/posts/wwdc-swiftui-lounge/#use-viewbuillder

Comment: @malhal, thanks for that suggestion.  Resolving the `ViewBuilder` and storing `content` as a `View` has the added benefit of fixing the OP's issue *if* they don't mind creating the view before it is *ready*.  I added this as a solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `content` in `LoadingView` until the data is loaded, so SwiftUI fails to recreate the `LoadingView` when `presentationMode` is updated.  There are a number of ways to fix this.

### Mark `content` as capturing `presentationMode`

If you mark the `content` of `LoadingView` as capturing `presentationMode`, then `LoadingView` will get updated when `presentationMode` changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum PresentationMode {
        case small, big
    }
    
    @State private var presentationMode: PresentationMode = .small
    
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView() { [presentationMode] message in
            switch presentationMode {
            case .small:
                Text("Small presentation of: \(message)")
            case .big:
                Text("Big presentation of: \(message)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("Presentation mode is changed, before data is loaded")
                self.presentationMode = .big
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Use `content` from the start

Because your `LoadingView` isn't using the `content` when `presentationMode` is changed, SwiftUI fails to recreate the `LoadingView` so it is stuck with the original value of `presentationMode`.

If you change your `LoadingView` to use the `content` but make it invisible until loaded, then the `LoadingView` will get updated when `presentationMode` changes:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        content("Data")
            .opacity(loaded ? 1 : 0)
        if !loaded {
            Text("Data is still loading")
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.loaded = true
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Enable `LoadingView` to control `loaded` State

If you only want the real `content` to be rendered when the data is loaded, you can wrap that content in `if loaded { }` and pass `loaded` as a `Binding` to the `LoadingView`, and then `LoadingView` can set `loaded = true` when the data is loaded, then the `PresenterView` will reload `LoadingView` with the real `content` which will use the latest versions of the `@State` variables:

```
struct PresenterView: View {
    
    enum PresentationMode {
        case small, big
    }
    
    @State private var presentationMode: PresentationMode = .small
    @State private var loaded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        LoadingView(loaded: $loaded) { message in
            if loaded {
                let _ = print("presenting now")
                switch self.presentationMode {
                case .small:
                    Text("Small presentation of: \(message)")
                case .big:
                    Text("Big presentation of: \(message)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                print("Presentation mode is changed, before data is loaded")
                self.presentationMode = .big
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct LoadingView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var loaded: Bool
    let content: (String) -> Content
    init(loaded: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (String) -> Content) {
        self._loaded = loaded
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content("Data")
            if !loaded {
                Text("Data is still loading")
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.loaded = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

### Store `content` as the `View` instead of the `ViewBuilder`

In the comments @malhal mentioned that it is a better practice to resolve the `View` in the `.init` and store it rather than storing the `ViewBuilder`.  This has the added benefit, in your case, of using the `ViewBuilder` immediately, thus ensuring that it will be updated when `presentationMode` changes:

```
struct LoadingView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @State var loaded = false
    
    let content: Content  // <- changes here
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (String) -> Content) {
        self.content = content("Data")  // <- here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if loaded {
                content  // <- and here
            }
            else {
                Text("Data is still loading")
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                print("Data is loaded")
                self.loaded = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions.  I think the best option is to try render the content as soon as possible (but I will try option 1 too). The only issue with that is that in my use case LoadingView is waiting for a network task to finish, so I would have to use some empty data as placeholder.